# python error : codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 2857: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, encoding

I am reading a latex file using

```
with open(inputFileName, 'r', encoding="utf8") as inputFileHandle:
    for lineInput in inputFileHandle:
```

It fails with lineInput showing "% Declare common style"
with the error

```
can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 2857: invalid continuation byte
```

I can not see any strange characters in the latex file. What is the byte 0xe4 and how can I identify it in the tex file?

Comment: 0xe4 is `'ä'`, 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS'

Comment: If `lineInput` ever actually held the value "% Declare common style", then *that isn't the line with the error* - it's presumably the next line of the file that's the problem.  I would guess that the file simply isn't saved in utf-8 encoding, either resave it that way, or change the encoding parameter to `open()` to match the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: There was a single "ä" in the whole file. I converted the file from ansi to utf8 and now it works.